# retrieve data from mongodb and insert inside a script from a html

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, http, maps

hello guys i developed an android app that http post req some data like latitude, longitude and IMEI to server that post in database. everything is working fine, but now comes the second part of the project. I need to make an web application that shows me on map a market with the lat and long saved in database and i don't understand how. I understood i should use querys but i don't understand who to use them.

this is my server side.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

  //connect to mongodb:

    /*mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://tudorstanciulescu:19970826@test- 
    srqul.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: 
    true} );

   */
   var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";




   //app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
   //app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.json());

   //var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   app.post('/postBazaDate',(req,res)=> {
       var latitudine = req.body.latitudine;
       var longitudine = req.body.longitudine; 
       var imei = req.body.imei;
       var dateTime = new Date();
     ;
      var data = {
        "latitude" : latitudine,
        "longitute" : longitudine,
        "imei" : imei,
        "dateTime" : dateTime


      }
    //   data.save()
    //   .then(item => {

    //     res.send("item saved to database");
    //   })
    //   .catch(err => {
    //     res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    //   });

      MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err,               
  db)  {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection("date_locatie").insertOne(data, function(err, res) 
  {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document inserted");

        });
      });
```

i don't have any errors, everything is working fine, but i can't understand how to use the data from database in a script from an html

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, same place where you have added app.post

app.get('/getBazaDate',(req,res)=> {

```
      MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err,               
  db)  {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection("date_locatie").find({}, function(err, data) 
  {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.send(data); // here data is containing all saved data in array 
            //format

        });
      });


in html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The = Operator</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

const userAction = async () => {
fetch('http://localhost:3000/getBazaDate')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
}
userAction();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response.json;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple REST Explanation**

Ok so first is first, an html file is static and its contents can only be manipulated through javascript or css or someother language. Therefore, either you fetch the data before you load the page and send the data with the page , or you create an ajax call to get the data.

In a rest architecture you have GET , PUT , PATCH,  POST ,DELETE Requests, each request is to either create ,read , or update the database.

A GET is to send data from server -> client, therefore a client requests data from the server and the server fetches and prepares the data for the client and sends it back.

Both PUT and PATCH updates the data in the database
A POST is to send from client -> server and save data
A DELETE to delete a row from the database

For more information about restfull you can visit this website: https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

or do a quick google search rest tutorial and you will find many !

**Code Time**

**SERVER SIDE (USE ONE OF THESE)**  :

```
// app.js

// THIS GETS ONE ROW AND RETURNS OBJECT FROM THE DATABASE ACCORDING TO YOUR QUERY
app.get("/", (req,res,next) {       
     dbo.collection("date_locatie").find({}, function(err, res) {
         if (err) throw err;
         res.send(data);
     });
})

// THIS GETS MANY ROWS AND RETURNS ARRAY FROM THE DATABASE ACCORDING TO YOUR QUERY
app.get("/", (req,res,next) {    
     dbo.collection("date_locatie").findAll({}, function(err, res) {
         if (err) throw err;
         res.send(data);
     });
})
```

Now that your server is setup to get accept a GET REQUEST AND send back the data
All you have to do is call the url using an ajax call in javascript and your data will be sent to the client's pc.

To show the data you need to loop (if its array) and append data to HTML.

**CLIENT SIDE** :

In an html file you can write javascript in a script tag. This allows for the DOM elements to be manipulated. Supposed you have an empty  with id locationData
and you want to fill it with the data that you saved

```
//index.html 
//Assuming you are using jQuery 
<div id="locationData"></div>
<script>

    // WHEN HTML IS FULLY LOADED SENDS A GET REQUEST TO YOUR SERVER TO FETCH 
    // THE DATA

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3000/", success: function(result){

        // PUTS THE DATA IN THE DIV WITH ID : locationData
           $("#locationData").html(result);
        }});
    });

<script>
```